Structure of SS5 derived from cinnamic acid
What is the structure and molecular formula of a compound derived from cinnamic acid with the abbreviation SS5? The molecular formula I found on PubChem for SS5 was $\ce{C29H34N4O2},$ but I don't know if it's correct.

Cinnamic acid is : $\ce{C9H8O2}$. It is far from your formula, except for the number of oxygen atoms.

Try googling cinnamic acid derivates ss5. It brings interesting results.

@Maurice Complete edits are preferred. Putting a single formula in math mode when the entire post is barely readable is a questionable improvement. To OP: what is the context of the question (where does "SS5" come from?) and the PubChem URL?

is it (2S)-1-[3-(cyclohexylmethoxy)phenyl]-3-[5-(3-methyl-1H-indazol-5-yl)pyridin-3-yl]oxy-propan-2-amine ? from here : https://www.rcsb.org/ligand/SS5

it has the right formula but not sure how you get to it from cinnamic acid? looks more like an indole connected to a couple more aromatic rings

Your question is not very clear that what type of chemical is SS5. If it is a kinase inhibitor, then according to PDB, the following is the structure of SS5 ligand, which has molecular formula of $\ce{C29H34N2O2}$ (formula mass: $\pu{470.606 g mol-1}$):

As you see, it is not cinnamic acid derived, but rather $\alpha,\beta$-dihydro-cinnamyl alcohol derived (the structure of cinnamyl alcohol is is inserted for comparison). The SS5 ligand is similar to pyridine–pyrazolopyridine-based inhibitors of protein kinase B/Akt described in Ref. 1:


Reference 1:
Gui-Dong Zhu, Jianchun Gong, Viraj B. Gandhi, Keith Woods, Yan Luo, Xuesong Liu, Ran Guan, Vered Klinghofer, Eric F. Johnson, Vincent S. Stoll, Mulugeta Mamo, Qun Li, Saul H. Rosenberg, and Vincent L. Giranda, "Design and synthesis of pyridine–pyrazolopyridine-based inhibitors of protein kinase B/Akt," Bioorganic & Medicinal Chemistry 2007, 15(15), 2441-2452 (DOI: https://doi.org/10.1016/j.bmc.2007.01.010).
